# Stop Images Disappearing when scrolling UITableView

Tags: iphone, caching, uiimage, uitableview

I have a UI Table View Controller. Each Cell Loads an image from my webserver.
If I scroll the TableView so that a particular cell scrolls out of view and then scroll back again the image for that cell has vanished and I have to wait for it to reload.

I'm guessing this is some performance/ memory management thing build into iphone?

How can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the cells in the tableview are recycled.

cache the images in memory and assign from your cache rather than loading the images directly into the tableview

I don't know if this is best practice or not but I think you could use an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` of `UIImage` and load into there first and just assign references to the objects in the array.

**Update**

There is some code [here](http://www.ericd.net/2009/05/iphone-caching-images-in-memory.html) which uses an `NSMutableDictionary` for the cache